# Dynamic width of 'inline-block' while resizing window

Tags: css, width

I put several tables (`display: inline-block` & fixed column width: 140px) side by side seperated by a 100px margin.
► [CodePen / Original code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rLbWxz)

I want these margins to reduce when I resize the width of the window so that the line doesn't collapse too soon. I did find a way to do that, but it's hacky and I don't really like this solution.
► [CodePen / Hacky solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QEPGNG)

**Exemple:**

```
<div class="tab_centre" style="font-size: 0px;">
<table style="font-size: 12px;"><thead><tr><th class="etat0">Env 3a</th><th class="etat0">Env 3b</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>v1.2</td><td>v1.2</td></tr></tbody></table>
<div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 100px; width: calc(100vw - 840px - 135px);"></div>
<table style="font-size: 12px;"><thead><tr><th class="etat0">Env 4a</th><th class="etat0">Env 4b</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>v1.2</td><td>v1.2</td></tr></tbody></table>
<div style="display: inline-block; max-width: 100px; width: calc(100vw - 840px - 135px);"></div>
<table style="font-size: 12px;"><thead><tr><th class="etat0">Env 5a</th><th class="etat0">Env 5b</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>v1.1+</td><td>v1.1+</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

Is there a way to avoid `max-width: 100px; width: calc(100vw - 840px - 135px);`?
The values inserted in the 'calc' are an hit-and-miss.

Comment: Have you tried using % instead of px, `margin-right: 2%;`

Answer (score 1):

You should give margin in percentage instead of px.

```
margin-right: 2%;
```

Comment: I'm not sure too get what you meant. The margin width is still static with "2%".